# Rails, variables rendered as `nil`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

My controller is :

```
require 'date'
class DateController < ApplicationController
def wee
        @thing=DateTime.now
        @va1=12345
end
end
```

My view is:

```
<h1>Date#show</h1>
<pre><%= @thing.inspect %></pre>
<pre><%= @va1.inspect %></pre>
<p>Find me in app/views/date/show.html.erb</p>
```

and the resulting page is:

```
Date#show

nil

nil

Find me in app/views/date/show.html.erb
```

Why are my variables not displayed? Is ther such thing as a naming scope in controllers?
Can I call `<%= anothercontoller.variable %>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you really want to name your action as `wee`, just do the following:

1. rename your view template as `wee.html.erb`
2. in the `/config/routes.rb` file, add:

   ```
   resources :dates do
     member do
       get :wee
     end
   end
   ```

which is definitely more complicated than other answers. But it will solve the problem if you insist on the naming. The problem is that the naming do not match each other so that the instance variables do not pass to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Problably because you have `wee` method in `DataController` but using view for `show` action.

Answer (score 2):

create a show method in your controller, then write your queries there.

```
 def show 
   @thing = DateTime.now
   @va1 = 12345
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming you controller method name from "wee" => "show"